# How list comprehensions works here?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am have read python documentations regarding list comprehensions I got an idea about list comprehensions work flow, but unable to understand the process involved in this code.

```
items=[x for x in raw_input().split(',')]
```

Comment: It is not output, it is an assignment.

Comment: Run it and try it yourself

Comment: What's the comprehension for? Isn't this equivalent to `items = raw_input().split(',')?`

Comment: @mpf82 - That's not a duplicate. There's no nesting here. It's just a shallow copy of a `str.split()` operation.

Comment: I interpreted the program and I got output too, But I didn't understand the syntax. @sameerasy

Comment: @JitendraReddy I don't understand your comment. You write that you know that it is output, it is not it, is an assigment of a list compression to the variable `items`, it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a list containing each word from input (from terminal) separated by comma `,`.

**Edit:**

```
items = [x for x in raw_input().split(',')]
print items
```

with input from terminal:

```
this, is, a, string
```

prints:

```
['this', ' is', ' a', ' string']
```

**Edit2**:

As pointed out in the comments, the list comprehension is redundant, and you would achieve the same using

```
items = raw_input().split(',')
```

**Edit3**:

Also mentioned in the comments, the above approach only works in python version 2. For python3, you'd use

```
items = input().split(',')                                                      
print (items)
```

Comment: It also assigns the list to the variable `items`

Comment: "x for x" what does it mean?

Comment: See the  link to the duplicate question. `raw_input().split(',')` returns a list, `x for x` iterates each element of that list.

Comment: That will throw a syntax error on the majority of maintained python versions.

Comment: why wouldn't one just use print raw_input().split(',')?

Comment: @MarcvT one would/should, but that's not what's asked in the question.